# Documents image are not visible on email

Tags: email-template

I've got some images on Documents **(all marked as externally available)** that are working properly on my Community custom component and on the HTML email template preview.
But if I send that email template, then the images are not rendered.

Here is the link of one image:

```
https://letsgetcheckedus--c.documentforce.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=0155G000007rLEA
```

And here is the usage of it inside the email template.

```
<img style="width: 300px;
                            height: auto;"  
                     src="https://letsgetcheckedus--c.documentforce.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=0155G000007rLEA" alt="Illustration" />
```

So seems like the checkbox to mark as external does not really make the images public, needing to have SF access, is that right?

Answer (score 0):

Ive managed to solve this. The link that I've showed was taken by clicking on the View button in Classic Document view.
We actually need to click on the Document record, right click on the image and open with another tab. Than we get that link which is public.